# How to use the negated approximate sign

Tags: symbols

I'm trying to get the negated `\approx` sign in LaTeX, as it is in here:

[image]

But the `\napprox` command does not work. Any ideas? Maybe it was switched to a new command? Or do I just need to include some package?

Comment: Have you tried `$\not\approx$`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: See: [How to look up a symbol?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol)

Comment: I'm already using the amssymb package ..

Comment: Question solved, I've used the \not \approx, thanks Corentin!

Comment: According to the Comprehensive LaTeX symbol lists, `\napprox` is defined by the `mathabx` package

Comment: @EmeritusJr -- some history ... when `amssymb` was created, space was at a premium, so negated relations that looked (and behaved) okay using `\not\xxx` weren't included.  you can make your life a little easier by making your own definition: `\newcommand{\napprox}{\not\approx}`

Answer (score 21):

The table you show is relative to the symbols provided by `mathabx`. One can say

```
\usepackage{mathabx}
```

but this will change many symbols and not always in a desirable way.

For negated relations one can first try preceding the command by `\not`:

```
\not\approx
```

The placement of the diagonal bar is not always ideal, which is why the negation of `\in` has its own command `\notin`. In the case of `\not\approx` there is no problem.

Here's a visual comparison: above the normal rendition of the symbol, using Computer Modern Math Symbols, below the `mathabx` rendition. A difference in shape is evident.

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Unless a font is used that contains the glyph `≉` (U+2249 NOT ALMOST EQUAL TO), the symbol is constructed by the two relational symbols `\not` and `\approx`. The appearance looks o.k., but the result from "copy & paste" is "suboptimal". This can be improved by package `accsupp` that uses the ActualText feature of PDF (for PDF viewers that support this feature such as Acrobat Reader):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{accsupp}
\providecommand*{\napprox}{%
  \BeginAccSupp{method=hex,unicode,ActualText=2249}%
  \not\approx
  \EndAccSupp{}%
}
\begin{document}
\[ a \napprox b \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Result from "copy & paste" (AR9/Linux): `a ≉ b`

Comment: It's nice that `\BeginAccSupp` and `\EndAccSupp` don't add items to the math list, so the spacing is correct (tested with a binary operator).

Comment: @egreg Yes, just whatsits are inserted (`\pdfliteral` or `\special`), no boxes. And I prefer `\begingroup` ... `\endgroup` for grouping. Curly braces for grouping would interfere by adding a subformula.